# Navigator Change Back Button color

Tags: react-native, button, navigation

How can I change the "< Back" this button color??

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass headerTintColor in navigationOptions which will be applied to the header. [Link here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headertintcolor)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react native router flux then you can set below code. Change colors according to your need

```
<Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login" backButtonTextStyle = {{color:'#000000'}}
                                                                                barButtonIconStyle={{ tintColor: '#000000' }}
                                                                                titleStyle = {{color : '#ffffff'}}
                                                                                navigationBarStyle = {{backgroundColor : '#1565c0'}}
                                                                                backButtonTintColor = '#ffffff'/> />
```